# What libc++ version supports three way comparison for STL types

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, libc++

I'm trying to compile simple code with C++20 support, clang 14/15 and libc++ 14/15
The code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct foo {
    std::string member{"Hello, Kitty!"};
    auto operator<=>(const foo&) const = default;
};
int main() {
    foo f;
    std::cout << f.member << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The CMakeList

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(three_way_comparison)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS 1)
add_compile_options("-stdlib=libc++")

add_executable(three_way_comparison main.cpp)
```

It fails with

```
> /home/user/CLionProjects/three-way-comparison/main.cpp:6:10: warning:
> explicitly defaulted three-way comparison operator is implicitly
> deleted [-Wdefaulted-function-deleted]
>     auto operator<=>(const foo&) const = default;
>          ^ /home/user/CLionProjects/three-way-comparison/main.cpp:5:17: note:
> defaulted 'operator<=>' is implicitly deleted because there is no
> viable three-way comparison function for member 'member'
>     std::string member{"Hello, Kitty!"};
>                 ^ /usr/lib/llvm-14/bin/../include/c++/v1/__utility/pair.h:340:1: note:
> candidate template ignored: could not match 'pair' against
> 'basic_string' yada, yada
```

the `/usr/lib/llvm-14/include/c++/v1/string` header indeed does not have the `operator<=>` in it. tried to run `sudo apt` to install `libc++-14-dev`, it didnt work. What I'm doing wrong? version `15` ends up with the same error.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20
10th line
+ `#include <compare>` or `<functionnal>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What libc++ version support three way comparison for STL types

The one that comes with clang++ 16.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qjbvY4857)

Comment: Aggggrrrrr! How did you find it? I spent half a day googling from what version what feature is supported, to no avail

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg I just tried it out until I found the version where it compiled. There may still be "holes" in the library implementation though. It's still listed as "partial" @ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Comment: I was looking at this link https://libcxx.llvm.org/Status/Spaceship.html, but go figure what version they mean, maybe devel?

Comment: and now, clang16 is missing std::optional spaceship operator

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg Yes, that is implemented in the trunk version so it'll be included in the next release